# How to add array items to a dictionary in visual basic

Tags: vb.net

The point of the program is to read a file, split the file into individual words, add the words to a dictionary, and then count how many instances of each word there are in the file.

```
Dim filename As String
Dim reader As StreamReader
Dim writer As StreamWriter
Dim wordCounts As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)

Console.Write("Please enter a filename: ")
filename = Console.ReadLine()

reader = File.OpenText(filename)

Dim lines As String = ""
Do Until reader.EndOfStream
    lines += reader.ReadLine()
Loop

Dim chunks As String()
Dim separators As String() = {" ", vbTab}
chunks = lines.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

This is what I have so far. I also have the code to count the instances so I don't need that. I would really appreciate any advice.

Comment: `vba <> vb.net`

Comment: Firstly, if you want to read the entire contents of a file into a `String`, just call `File.ReadAllText`. Simply pass it the file path and it returns the contents as a `String`. It handles all the opening, reading and closing for you.

Comment: As for your issue, what's your issue? Your question is better than some first tries but you haven't explained what your code actually does and how that differs from your expectations.

Comment: After the last line of your code, create a new `Dictionary(Of String, Integer)` say named `dict`, loop through the chunks `For Each chunk In chunks...`, check whether the word is already keyed `If dict.ContainsKey(chunk) Then` increase the value `dict(chunk) += 1` otherwise key it `dict.Add(chunck, 0)`.